# QDockWidget move problem when using custom title widget

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I want to create a dock widget with a custom title widget. That custom title widget has my own icons (maximize, minimize, close etc).

Source code is simply like that:

```
  QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget("name", parent);
  MyDockTitle * titleWidget = new MyDockTitle(dock);
  dock->setTitleBarWidget(titleWidget);
```

When I run the program, dock widget is shown appropriately but unfortunately I can not move the dock widget (it is in floating state). What can be the problem?

P.S. When I dont use custom title widget, I can move dock widget.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget) of setTitleBarWidget() says:

> Mouse events that are not explicitly
>   handled by the title bar widget must
>   be ignored by calling
>   QMouseEvent::ignore(). These events
>   then propagate to the QDockWidget 
>   parent, which handles them in the
>   usual manner, **moving when the title
>   bar is dragged**, docking and undocking
>   when it is double-clicked, etc.

So I guess you need to add some QMouseEvent::ignore() calls to your `MyDockTitle` class.